# How to get date range from week number with Luxon

Tags: javascript, luxon

I'm searching a way to get date range from week number with Luxon to replace my 'moment' code.
Today I'm using this code:

```js
m = moment(yearNumber + "-W" + weekNumber);
dateFromStr = moment(m.startOf('week')).add(1, 'day'); // To get Monday 00:00:00
dateToStr = moment(m.endOf('week')).add(1, 'day'); // To get Sunday 23:59:59
```

I found a way to do that from a month number with 'DateTime.fromObject()' but that's doesn't work with 'week'. So I don't find the best way to do that from a week number :(

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime.fromObject`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromobject) that:

> Create a DateTime from a JavaScript object with keys like 'year' and 'hour' with reasonable defaults.

passing `weekYear` (*an ISO week year*) and `weekNumber` (*an ISO week number, between 1 and 52 or 53, depending on the year*) in the input object.

Here an live example:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const yearNumber = 2020;
const weekNumber = 3;
const dt = DateTime.fromObject({
  weekYear: yearNumber,
  weekNumber: weekNumber
});

const dateFromStr = dt.startOf('week');
console.log(dateFromStr.toISO()); // last Monday at 00:00:00
const dateToStr = dt.endOf('week');
console.log(dateToStr.toISO()); // next Sunday at 23:59:59
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.26.0/build/global/luxon.js"></script>
```

You can also use [`DateTime.fromISO`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromiso) passing ISO compliant format such as `YYYY-Www` (see more on [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates)). Please note that week number should be two digits.

Comment: Thank's a lot, That's perfect :)